# Ionic datepicker mindate not working

Tags: ionic-framework, mindate

When I browse my ionic app in chrome, datePicker works fine

html:

```
<input name="from" type="date" ng-model="newOrder.dateFrom" min="{{minDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" required>
```

js:

```
 $scope.minDate = new Date();
```

But when i emulate the app, minDate doesnt work, you can select a date, but minimum date is not working. Does somenone know is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying out in iOS 7.1 emulator, as per the notes section present in this link http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime, it doesn't support min and max for the input type date. I tried the snippet you have shared in the iOS 8.1 and android 4.4 emulator and both seem to show up the min value properly.